# Wordpress string translation

Tags: php, wordpress, translation, wpml

i have follow issue. I want to add translation to the output in wordpress. In some sentences are variables. So i looked after a possibility to translate the sentence with the variable.

I found out that i can use printf with %s placeholder. If i execute the code the variable, which i want on place of %s get appended every time before the sentence.

Here is an example:

My Code:

```
printf( __('Have you already done the %s?', 'sage' ), $work);
```

have follow output:
**HouseworkHave you already done the ?**

Why the placeholder doesn't get replaced?

Comment: Hi :) At .pot file declare translate string with %s.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I solved it now. I used a function which printed the value. I used then an other function which only returns the value.